# Flutter pressing back in showDialog isn't caught

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm working on a component for my app that works like this: you're shown a first explanation page, you click a button to move to the second page with more text, then click another button that show a dialog.

When that dialog gets shown, I want to make sure the user can't use the "back button" to I did this:

```
showDialog(
      context: context,
      useSafeArea: false,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (context) {
        return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () async => false,
            child: ConfirmChoice(onContinuePressed: confirmCallback),
        );
      },
    );
```

For good measures, my `ConfirmChoice` widget is also wrapped in a `WillPopScope`
I thought using `WillPopScope` would allow the dialog to catch when back is pressed, but instead it's the widget bellow it that catches the action. That means that while the dialog is shown, if the users presses back on their android device, it navigates back to the first explanation page beneath the dialog!

Any idea what could be the cause and how I can fix it so pressing back while the dialog is shown does nothing ?